# My cat doesn't want me to sleep

Tags: cats, behavior

I'm an university student and I have a cat with an awesome character, that of course, is not a problem!

The thing is that lately my cat wants to play at 6:30- 7:00 am everyday and starts meowing and looking for attention. I'm doing lots of exams now so I go to bed late and I need to sleep more than my little cat wants.

What can I do? It looks like I should change my habits during exams period

Comment: Are you usually awake at that time? Cats don't recognize "variations to routine". You might also check the answer to this question: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11275/how-late-can-i-train-my-cats-to-let-me-sleep-in?rq=1 - you may find that for the few weeks of exam time you need to sleep with earplugs

Comment: Well I live with other people in this house so I could say that the day starts usually at 8, 7:30. I believe our cat is now starting to wake up earlier. Maybe is it because we change the food to a better one and he's anxious to eat ?

Comment: Feed the cat at breakfast tome, and you're training it to pester you for breakfast...

Comment: I am also the lucky owner of two alarm clocks; the buzz-alarm and the meow-alarm.  There is a button on the buzz-alarm to turn it off.  With the meow-alarm, there is only one thing you can do- get up and feed it.

Comment: All I have to say is welcome to adult life/ having a child lol I know this is by no means helpful

Comment: Well I guess I misunderstood who the pet was..

Answer (score 3):

Your cat may be waking your because it's hungry, or because it's bored. Or a combination.

If you feed the cat when you wake up, or shortly afterward, then it will associate waking you with getting fed. Perhaps you can feed the cat later, just before you leave for the day. Or leave a little dry food out the night before.

Now comes the fun part. When the cat wakes you, pull it close and snuggle it. You can do this without really waking up. Either the cat stays and you get a nice cat cuddle, or more likely, it runs off and leaves you alone for a bit. Either way, it's a win.

Comment: I apply both strategies. Mine do not get gooshyfood on anything resembling a regular schedule, so they have no reason to demand I wake up. And they are very used to curling up next to me for a nap -- in fact the most common reason for them to wake me is "it's cold, let me under the blanket."